# Any use to building up relationship with non party members?

Tags: persona-4-golden

Is there any advantage building up your relationship with non party members?

In P5 everybody you make a relationship with will give you a bonus ability or something.

But in P4 there seems to be no such thing. So is it a good idea to ignore relationships with non-party members (since they don't give you any advantage other than seeing their story?)

At least relationships with team members give them a few bonuses in the dungeons...

Spoiler:

> I know I also need to build up relationship with Marie before the epilogue to get the best ending. But except her, anything to get from other non party members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fuse a Persona of a specific Arcana, it gains bonus experience proportional to your rank in the corresponding Social Link, gaining up to five levels at max rank. Additionally, when you max out a Social Link, you gain the ability to fuse a new Persona you would not otherwise have access to.

Comment: I'm not much into the min/maxing so I do not care much about being able to make stronger personas. (In P5 I pretty much just went along the strategy of fuse your personas after each dungeon but except that i'm not going for the 'most op persona of all time') Is the more XP on fuse the only advantage?

Comment: @Fredy31 It's not really min-maxing; it's kind of the main point of the socal link system, but if you don't want stronger Personas, then I suppose there isn't a point in it.

Comment: I guess its just that coming from P5, not having the bonus abilities with social links the social links of non party members seem way less important then. Feels like these social link lose 50% their importance.

Comment: You also need at least half of the social links, including one specific one, at the maximum it can be, or you won't get the Good Ending.

Comment: @Shadur The only link that has any bearing on what ending you get is Marie's. This person is playing P4G of course, but in the original version, and for the original good ending in Golden, you don't need to go out of your way to get a *single* link maxed.

Comment: @angelos Unless that's drastically different in P4 as well, you need Adachi at 6 to get the Good Ending (or choose the Terrible Ending) regardless of whether or not you also do Marie.

Comment: @Shadur Ahh, it does appear that you need Adachi level 6 for the Golden epilogue, but you do not need to even start his link for the original good ending - he wasn't even a link in the PS2 version.